# Determining the path in Google Colab

Tags: python, path, google-colaboratory

Someone gave me access to their folder that contains an .ipynb notebook and several folders with files. I downloaded it and uploaded it in my Drive. Two of the sub-folders that I need are **Subfolder_A**, with a few `.txt` files, and **Subfolder_B**, which has other subfolders containing some machine learning models. I later uploaded some extra text files in **Subfolder_A**, for example `mytext.txt`.

I gave the path:

```
path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/The_Folder/"
t5 ="t5_ml_file"
ml_path = path + "Subfolder_B/" + t5
textname= path + "Subfolder_A/" + "mytext.txt"
f = open(textname,"r")
full_text = f.read()
```

I get an error on the third to last line, saying it doesn't find the `mytext.txt` file. I think the path is given correctly because otherwise I would have had an error on the `ml_path` line. The exact error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/The_Folder/Subfolder_A/mytext.txt'
```

It doesn't work for any of my new uploaded text, only for the one that was already there, given by the person who gave me access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mount the drive ?
Before calling it you must mount the drive:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I wrote it at the beginning of the notebook. I checked and it does find the `/content/gdrive/MyDrive/The_Folder/Subfolder_A/`. It just doesn't find the file.

Comment: maybe your file wasn't uploaded properly? do you see it when you navigate on the left hand menu?

Comment: Under Files it says: Connecting to a runtime to enable file browsing. But I checked with `!ls /content/gdrive/'MyDrive'/The_Folder/Subfolder_A` and it indeed only finds the text that was already there and not what I uploaded later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved by installing Ipython on my collab, so it will show up the new files added after the environment is already running.

```
!pip install Ipython --upgrade
```

So then, for new files, I run:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```